# Using Qt and cmake to store static files into /usr/share

Tags: qt, cmake, cross-platform

I use Qt and cmake for my open source application, which is targeted at Windows and Linux currently. It is written in C++. Tarballs and debian packages can be generated using cmake, while InnoSetup is used for generating Windows setup packages.

I know Qt has QSettings for storing user-specific persistent data and is cross platform. I'm not asking about this.

I have some architecture-independent, purely static, non-user-specific data (basically some XML files that never change) which I want to install together with my executables.

From what I understand, in Linux, this should be installed into /usr/share/[application] or /usr/local/share/[application]. OTOH, in Windows, this should be installed in C:\Program Files\[application].

1. How do I use the `install` command in cmake to achieve this for Linux?
2. Does Qt have any cross-platform API to auto-detect the location of these files after installation, just like it does for QSettings?

Comment: It's probably not what you want, but I should mention that Qt has [the resource system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/resources.html) that is used to store such data in the application's executable. It's quite convenient if files are not large. You can store any files, and they will be available through the Qt API in a way similar to a virtual file system.

Comment: No. The Qt resource system is used to store files into the executable like images and icons. What I want to do is keep a bunch of XML files outside the executable. These are like plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer #1, but maybe [QStandardPaths](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) is what you're looking for for #2?

Comment: I've looked at these, but they seem to contain user-specific paths. Do you know which one of the [standard locations](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum) would provide /usr/share? (I'm currently using Qt4 by the way. I haven't migrated to Qt5 that provides this)

Comment: With Qt 4.8, `qDebug() << QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation);` gives me `"/home/micurtis/.local/share/data//guitest"`. With Qt 5.2, `qDebug() << QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);` gives me `("/home/micurtis/.local/share", "/usr/share/kde-plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share")`. I'm not sure how you'd do this with 4.8 in that case. :/